# What it mean roundingMode in a converterNumber ADF Jdev 12c

Tags: formatting, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

Hi I want to know what it mean this roundingModes in ADF Jdev 12c, an explanation foreach rounding mode:

[image: The Rounding Modes availables for this attribute]

Greatings and thanks in advance.

Comment: http://jdevadf.oracle.com/adf-richclient-demo/docs/tagdoc/af_convertNumber.html. roundingMode java.math.RoundingMode Yes Specifies how numbers will be rounded. Default value is the JDK default for NumberFormat, usually RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN.

Comment: Thanks, I have another question, you know why the input show me the correct value for 123,123.01 but when the value is stored in his respectively field store something like 123123.007777....

Comment: depends on the datatype of the field i assume. you can use ui hints & UI conversion/formating to set the display for a field so the internal storage is not an issue.